# Vertical spacing of chapters numbers in ClassicThesis

Tags: spacing, classicthesis

I would to remove the upper line in chapters titles provided from the lineheaders option of  `classicthesis`. I want to know if the vertical spacing of the chapters numbers is correct also if I have removed that line.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
           eulerchapternumbers,
           pdfspacing,%
           linedheaders,%
           ]{classicthesis}


    \newcommand*{\titlevspace}[1]{\vspace*{\dimexpr #1\textheight - 1\baselineskip \relax}}

    % chapters
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
    {% lines above and below, number right
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
        {\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    \titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]%
        {\relax}{}{0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }

    % spacing

    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2.4\baselineskip}



\begin{document}

\chapter{Dolor}

\end{document}
```

---

in this line the `\\` at the end, should be maintained?

```
  {\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
```

or the titles look better with this settings?

```
  {\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please reformulate and maybe add a picture where you indicate what should change.

Comment: @StephanLehmke i would simply know if the vertical spacing of the chapter number from the chapter title is correct also if I have removed the upper line provided from the lineheaders option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you not only removed the upper horizontal rule but you also added some vertical spacing before the title and suppressed some vertical spacing (`\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}`) between the number and the chapter title; in the case of numbered chapters this makes sense (keeping the space without the rule would make the title appear too separate from the number), however, in the case of unnumbered chapters, I would suggest you to maintain the spacing. Your code then would look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
           eulerchapternumbers,
           pdfspacing,%
           linedheaders,%
           ]{classicthesis}


\newcommand*{\titlevspace}[1]{\vspace*{\dimexpr #1\textheight - 1\baselineskip \relax}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
  {\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
  {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}  
  [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]%
  {\relax}{}{0pt}%
  {\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}
  [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{2.4\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Dolor}

\end{document}
```

About the new request in the edit to the original question, suppressing the `\\` might cause the title to appear too close to the number for some long tiles, so I would keep some vertical spacing:

```
{\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}
```

If you consider the vertical space to be too big, you could use the optional argument of `\\` to reduce it a little using, for example, something like

```
{\titlevspace{.2125}}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\[-1ex]}{0pt}
```

Comment: thanks i have added a detail at my question could you give a look at it and give my your impression?

Comment: @FormlessCloud I've updated my answer.